# Ubuntu 16.04 fails to recognize headphones in jack or recognizes them but fails to output sound through them

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, headphones

first question here for me, thanks in advance for your help.
This bug is new and only started happening sometime this week, possibly after routine update.
Usually the OS recognizes when headphones are jacked in or out and adjusts volume accordingly, but now it either fails to do so, or recognizes the headphones but then does not output any sound. Laptop speakers are still working as usual.
The laptop is a Dell inspiron, dual booted with Win 10 where the sound still works as usual.

Any ideas what could be causing this? If you think you can help please provide easy step by step assistance as I'm a linux noob (:

Comment: It sounds like an previous question for which I gave the following answer. Please havge a look at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/963138/volume-keys-stop-working-when-i-switch-audio-outputs